# I have a multi-dimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a array like this :

```
$datpoint =   Array([0] => Array([x] => Aug 08,2016 [y] => 0) [1] => Array  [x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0 )[2] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[3] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[4] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0) );
```

and I want this array in below format:

```
$dataPoints = array( array("y" => 6, "label" => "aug 2, 2016"),array("y" => 4, "label" => "aug 15, 2016"), array("y" => 5, "label" => "sep 1, 2016"),array("y" => 7, "label" => "sep 18, 2016"), array("y" => 4, "label" => "Nov 1, 2016"),array("y" => 6, "label" => "Oct 21, 2016 "),array("y" => 7, "label" => "dec 11, 2016"),array("y" => 0, "label" => "dec 31, 2016"), array("y" => 0, "label" => "jan 1, 2016") );
```

It consider a great help.

Comment: what are these new values to y and label.they are different from original array.

Comment: I want to passs [x] and [y] in place of  [y] and [labe] .

Comment: let's consider this :

Comment: $datpoint =   Array([0] => Array([x] => Aug 08,2016 [y] => 0) [1] => Array  [x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0 )[2] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[3] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[4] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0) );
$dataPoints = array( array("y" => 6, "x" => "aug 2, 2016"),array("y" => 4, "x" => "aug 15, 2016"), array("y" => 5, "x" => "sep 1, 2016"),array("y" => 7, "x" => "sep 18, 2016"), array("y" => 4, "x" => "Nov 1, 2016"),array("y" => 6, "x" => "Oct 21, 2016 "),array("y" => 7, "x" => "dec 11, 2016"),array("y" => 0, "x" => "dec 31, 2016"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataPoints = array( array("y" => 6, "x" => "aug 2, 2016"),array("y" => 4, "x" => "aug 15, 2016"), array("y" => 5, "x" => "sep 1, 2016"),array("y" => 7, "x" => "sep 18, 2016"), array("y" => 4, "x" => "Nov 1, 2016"),array("y" => 6, "x" => "Oct 21, 2016 "),array("y" => 7, "x" => "dec 11, 2016"),array("y" => 0, "x" => "dec 31, 2016")); 

 foreach($dataPoints as $key=>$val){
    $dataPoints[$key]['label']=$val['x'];
    unset($dataPoints[$key]['x']);
 }

echo "</pre>";
print_r($dataPoints);
```

Comment: I have this array : $datpoint1 =  array( Array([0] => Array([x] => Aug 08,2016 [y] => 0) [1] => Array  [x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0 )[2] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[3] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0)[4] => Array([x] => Aug 03,2016 [y] => 0) )
Want  it as $dataPoints2
$dataPoints2 = array( array("y" => 6, "x" => "aug 2, 2016"),array("y" => 4, "x" => "aug 15, 2016"), array("y" => 5, "x" => "sep 1, 2016"),array("y" => 7, "x" => "sep 18, 2016"), array("y" => 4, "x" => "Nov 1, 2016"),array("y" => 6, "x" => "Oct 21, 2016 "),array("y" => 7, "x" => "dec 11, 2016") );

Comment: why the values are different in both array. from where 5,7 are coming.